# typechecking for compose funcion in python does not seem to work

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to annotate the type of a 'compose' function, and I can't get mypy to tell me I am wrong.

In the code below, the definitions of first and eval work as expected, changing the return type to (say) int gives me an error.

However, the definition for compose does not. I can change the return value of the resulting function to pretty much anything, and mypy does not notice it.

Is is supposed to be like that? What can I do to get typechecking that checks is particular type?

```
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
H = TypeVar('H')

def first(l: Sequence[T], h : Sequence[S]) -> tuple[T,S]:
    return (l[0],h[0])

def eval(f : Callable[[T],S], arg : T) -> S :
    return f(arg)

def compose (f : Callable[[T],S], g : Callable[[H],T]) -> Callable[[H],int]: #no complaints?
    def aux(x):
        a = g(x)
        b = f(a)
        return b
    return aux
```

Comment: Well hello there! As the author of [`compose`](https://pypi.org/project/compose) and someone who has paid some attention to `toolz` discussions about this problem, I am pleasantly surprised to see that another person is taking a stab at trying to solve this problem. (I'd like to write an answer but might not get to it for a couple days.)

Comment: That's because your `aux` is untyped, and so is equivalent to `def aux(x: Any) -> Any` for type checkers. Add annotations to `aux` and see it working. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=7c91a547bbf7f72126f51ccddd082691

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks for the link to mypy-play.net by the way! I've been putting off getting fluent with Python's type hinting and haven't yet remembered any online playgrounds for quick testing of type hints, so that's really helpful!

Comment: @mtraceur here's also one for pyright (not sure it's up-to-date, but it's funny to compare several checkers sometimes): https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/

Comment: @mtraceur, I checked `compose`. It does not have type hints yet, right? (given the difficulty with an arbitrary number of functions)

Comment: @SUTerliakov, that was that! Problem fixed (for now)

Comment: @josinalvo yeah, no type hints for now. (The difficulty/impossibility of making it variadic is one reason - another is that no one has asked me for them and I personally haven't yet felt strongly eager to go out of my way to provide them... however, I keep seeing more desire for it, such as this question, so I've been increasingly thinking about finally getting around to it.)

Comment: I see.

The easy solution is to add type hints for compose2, compose3... compose7
(ie: compose 2 functions, compose 3 functions...)

Haskell does that sometimes (create multiple versions, considering argument number) when the type system prevents more elegant solutions

Comment: @josinalvo yeah, we can actually take it one step further with [type hint overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)! So we could define type hint overloads for `compose` arities up to some large number, and hope that no one ever needs type hinting for a larger composition. I was going to mention it in my answer but when I tried it, it seemed that MyPy had issues with  `typing.overload` in the same file as the code - I hope to soon test it in a separate typing stub file, and if it works then that's probably the best we can do.

Comment: @josinalvo the next challenge after that, in my case, is that my `compose` returns callable objects rather than plain functions, which ends up needing a more complex approach with type hints, so if I can get `@overload` working, I'll need to also figure out how to bring that solution over from plain functions (returning closures) to class definitions where the `__init__` and `__call__` have to have correlated overloads (I think that's doable, maybe with [variadic generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple), but I haven't thought it through yet).

Comment: @josinalvo Update: [`compose`](https://pypi.org/project/compose) now has type hints (optional, installed separately as [`compose-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/compose-stubs))! It turned out that my last comment was unnecessary - even when `compose` is implemented as a class with callable instances, its type hint overloads can be simple functions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add types to the inner function, and for the most generic solution you need [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec).

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec


T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
P = ParamSpec('P')


def compose(f: Callable[[S], T], g: Callable[P, S]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    def _composed(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        a = g(*args, **kwargs)
        b = f(a)
        return b
    return aux
```

Of course, if you're just hard-coding one argument to the composed function, you don't need `ParamSpec` — just `TypeVar` is enough:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
R = TypeVar('R')


def compose(f: Callable[[S], R], g: Callable[[T], S]) -> Callable[[T], R]:
    def _composed(arg: T) -> R:
        a = g(arg)
        b = f(a)
        return b
    return aux
```

The bigger challenge is generalizing this to a variadic `compose`. Python's type hinting system is very limited when it comes to variadics. As far as I know, currently the only way is to use [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) to define a separate type hint for each arity. For example, here's what I do in the type stubs for my [`compose`](https://pypi.org/project/compose) library:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload


P = ParamSpec('P')
R1 = TypeVar('R1')
R2 = TypeVar('R2')
R3 = TypeVar('R3')
# and so on up to whatever arity you want to support.


@overload
def compose(f1: Callable[P, R1], /) -> Callable[P, R1]:
    ...
@overload
def compose(f2: Callable[[R1], R2], f1: Callable[P, R1], /) -> Callable[P, R2]:
    ...
@overload
def compose(f3: Callable[[R2], R3], f2: Callable[[R1], R2], f1: Callable[P, R1], /) -> Callable[P, R3]:
    ...
# and so on up to whatever arity you want to support.
```